# positive solutions to a homogeneous linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an m by n matrix A (of real numbers), I would like an algorithm to determine if there exists a solution to the linear equation Ax=0 whose coordinates are all strictly positive.

Note: It is not required that the coordinates of the solution be integer valued.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: In general, the homogeneous equation will have infinitely many solutions. How can I check them all?

Comment: The problem is stated in a mathematical way because that is the cleanest way to express it. It comes from a very common problem in graphics.

Comment: I understood that my suggestions don't cover all cases. Forget them.

Comment: Most numerical packages include a general non-negative least squares solver, e.g., [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html) & [matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lsqnonneg.html). The former is a wrapper to [NNLS](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.18.0/scipy/optimize/nnls/nnls.f) in Fortran, while the latter references a book which specifies the algorithm. I’m not sure if the constrained problem (where right-hand-side is 0, i.e., homogeneous solution) is any easier to solve than the general case, I’ll dig around.

Comment: Also relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30048/existence-uniqueness-of-nonnegative-solutions-of-linear-systems-of-equations

Comment: I don't see how least squares solvers are relevant here. As far as I know, those are only for finding approximate solutions to over determined linear systems, which Ax=0 certainly is not.

Comment: One can always use `nnls` and see if the residual’s norm (error `||A . x||`) is zero. Do you have an example `A` handy? And is `m > n`?

Comment: You can always use **linear programming**. You have the equality constraint `A x = 0` and the inequality constraint `x >= 0`. Pick an arbitrary objective function.